# Interpretation of unramified primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $p$ be prime. Then $$(p) = p\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p_1}^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p_r}^{e_r}$$ where the $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s are distinct prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$. If $e_i=1$ for all $i$, then $p$ is said to be unramified.

My question: Is my interpretation correct that if $q$ is prime (prime in sense of domains) divisor of unramified $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $q^2$ cannot divide $p$?

My attempt: Since $q$ divides $p$, then $p\in(q)$ and $(q)$ is a prime ideal so $(q)=\mathfrak{p_i}$ for some $i$. Since $p$ is unramified, $q^2$ does not divide $p$, otherwise, $e_i\geq2$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works! In fact, you can say more: if $p\in\Bbb{Z}$ is a prime unramified in $K$ and $a\in\mathcal{O}_K$ is a nonzero nonunit, then $a^2$ cannot divide $p.$ If it did, you could write $a^2b = p$ for some $b\in\mathcal{O}_K,$ and then passing to ideals and factoring $(a^2b) = (a)^2(b)$ into primes shows that any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ (and there must be at least one such prime, because $(a)$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$) dividing $(a)$ would divide $p\mathcal{O}_K$ at least twice.